# Sfml c# linux как компилить?

Tags: c#, linux, sfml

Как работать с sfml на с# в линукс. Есть идея с моно, но есть желание разрабатывать сразу на ubuntu и запускать. (В дальнейшем  планирую игру перенести на raspberry, поэтому такой вопрос)

Comment: чел, C# на линуксе хоть и можно, но так делать нехорошо. на c++ sfml тоже есть

Comment: собственно «с# для linux» — это и есть mono... в его сторону и надо копать, других вариантов нет...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверял лично. В ubuntu 18.04. Связка `.Net Core 3.1` и `Rider` в качестве среды разработки. Создал новый проект консольного приложения, установил nuget пакет SFML.NET. Проект компилируется и при запуске открывается рабочее окно игры.

Прошел первые 3 урока по этому [видео](https://youtu.be/rcNlR_Loz0g?list=PLG2i_rSSIXXqHn4XrBP2qR4OjhQAFF9M3). Только он там вручную пакеты в проект внедряет, я это понятное дело так не делал, а просто установил nuget пакет.
[image: изображение окна разработки]

Comment: Круто, мерси большое, попробовал, понравилось (пока не тестил на raspberry, но думаю будет все круто)